# Compare numeric values inside a jsonb field of postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgres-10

I have a column inside a postgresql database table of type `jsonb` called `meta`. This is the data i have inside one of the rows in the meta column of the table.

```
{
    budget: {
        data: "2018-12-15",
        target: 47.5,
        spend: 12.3
    } 
}
```

I am trying to write a query that return all rows where

```
meta.budget.spend < meta.budget.target
```

or

```
meta.budget.date != "2018-12-15"
```

I tried

```
SELECT ... WHERE (("table"."meta"#>>'{budget,spend}') < "table"."meta"#>>'{budget,target}'
       OR ("table"."meta"#>>'{budget,date}') != '2018-12-15')
```

and i got 0 row as a result. I'm I doing the query right? If not, how do i fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
SELECT *
  ,(meta->'budget'->'target')::text::numeric(10,2) AS target
  ,(meta->'budget'->'spend')::text::numeric(10,2) AS spend
FROM tab
WHERE (meta->'budget'->'spend')::text::numeric(10,2) < 
      (meta->'budget'->'target')::text::numeric(10,2)
   OR (meta->'budget'->'data')::text::date != '2018-12-15'::date
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5c61e1ecd2518a5ff7d90228600c1494)**

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that [`#>>` gives you `text`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE):

> **Operator**: `#>>`
>   **Right Operand Type**: `text[]`
>   Get JSON object at specified path as text

and `text` won't necessarily compare the way you want. If you add a couple type casts, you'll get better results:

```
   ("table"."meta" #>> '{budget,spend}')::numeric < ("table"."meta" #>> '{budget,target}')::numeric
OR ("table"."meta" #>> '{budget,date}')::date != '2018-12-15'
```

You could also say `'2018-12-15'::date` if you like to be explicit but that's implied by the `date` on the left hand side.

Comment: when i do this i this is the error i get `SequelizeDatabaseError: operator does not exist: text < numeric`

Comment: I think you're missing the `::numeric` typecast on the left side, see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=afab6da2591fb4d469ef2e873080271c for an example.